# In Vim can you stop the color change of white space characters with 'set cursorline' on?

Tags: vim, line, text-cursor

In this Vim screenshot you can see that when moving the cursor over a line it changes the normal color of the whitespace characters (shown on the left) from grey to black. Can I stop this and leave them showing grey always, regardless of cursor position?

[image]

I've tried setting these in the colour scheme but no luck:

```
hi SpecialKey  guibg=bg  guifg=#CCCCCC gui=none
hi NonText     guibg=bg  guifg=#CCCCCC gui=none
```

Comment: How did you turn that on in the first place? I want.

Comment: :set list / :set listchars=eol:$,tab:>-,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<

Comment: Nice, can it work with tabexpand?

Comment: No idea, take a look at the vim help.

Comment: @regality If tabs are expanded into spaces, this won’t work.

Comment: A patch that implements the change has been proposed on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php): [display of listchars characters on the cursorline & visual-mode](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/oYeTcHINrrg/u4NmKV8pmGcJ)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:match` to highlight the tabs.

```
:match NonText '^\s\+'
```

That seems to override the cursor line. It would be better of course to use `matchadd()` but it seems to be overriden by the cursor line. There might be a way to make it work

Comment: You can use matchadd() if you put it in ~/.vim/after/

Comment: @JohnEikenberry can you elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: @tam5 By putting it in ~/.vim/after/ it will run after everything else is set up so it can't be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

Following lines in .vimrc fixed the problem for me.

```
au VimEnter * call matchadd('SpecialKey', '^\s\+', -1)
au VimEnter * call matchadd('SpecialKey', '\s\+$', -1)
```

It overrides other styles application for tabs and trailing spaces inside a cursor line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  From `:help listchars` (at the end):

> The "NonText" highlighting will be used for "eol", "extends" and
>   "precedes".   "SpecialKey" for "nbsp", "tab" and "trail".

With this knowledge you can modify your color scheme accordingly or add a call to `highlight` in your vimrc.

Comment: I've already set these: hi SpecialKey guibg=bg guifg=#CCCCCC gui=none
hi NonText guibg=bg guifg=#CCCCCC gui=none

Comment: Perhaps you have `cursorline` turned on?  Try `set nocursorline` to turn it off.

Comment: I'm sorry, ignore that, I can't believe it's in your question title and I didn't read it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have 'cursorline' set. The `CursorLine` highlight group defines the highlights for the same. Either you `set nocursorline`, (which can speed line movements) or change the `CursorLine` highlight groups fg colors.

Comment: The `CursorLine` highlight group overrides whitespace characters regardless of its fg colours. I believe this is precisely the problem the OP is facing