# Match end of line (EOL) with syntax match in vim

Tags: regex, vim, match, eol, end-of-line

When I hit `/` in vim and search for `$` it highlights all eols. But when I try to match them with `syntax match` it does not seem to work.

```
function! ConcealNonText()
    set conceallevel=1
    set concealcursor=v
    syntax match NonText /$/ conceal cchar=¶
endfunction

augroup ConcealNonText
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * call ConcealNonText()
augroup END
```

Any hints how I could match it in order to display eols as concealed chars?
I know I could use `set list listchars` but that has some [visual side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248872/in-vim-can-you-stop-the-color-change-of-white-space-characters-with-set-cursorl) in my opinion.

Comment: Well the pattern should rather be `[\n]` - nevertheless that does not give me better results.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your requirement is to show `¶` in place of the eol. Although the code you have given maybe a possible solution, but it surely is not an ideal one. Vim provides a much simpler way of achieving what you wish. What you really need to do is lookup `:h listchars`.

Following is an example of what you should put in your vimrc to achieve what you desire :

```
set list
set listchars+=eol:¶
```

Once you put this, vim will show the character `¶` for the eol character.

Comment: Thanks, but I know that already, see OP and the link provided which describes the problem with listchars.

Answer (score 0):

to do what you want, you can do `matchadd()` to match all end of lines. Matchadd will return an id that will help you delete that given match when you want.

```
:call matchadd("NonText", "$")
```

See `:he matchadd()` for more informations on how to use it.

HTH

Comment: As far as I know ```conceal``` can only be applied to ```syntax match```. So I guess it wouldn't work as expected?

Comment: No, but you'd better use `set listchars+=eol:¶` with the matchadd, then you'll have all line endings with the `¶` character, but using a match, instead of the syntax, for the color. That's actually an option I'm considering for my own configuration, as I also regret having my eol character loosing its coloration attributes when under the cursorline.