# Set visibility and/or color of listchars or conceal cchar in vim when cursorline is highlighting a line

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I know that I can use set `list listchars=...` to show `NonText` and `SpecialKey` characters in order to highlight different kinds of, well non-text characters. In general this is straight forward and works. But it has a visual side effect which disturbes me - while "hovering" the cursor over a line when the cursorline is set to on `listchars` are highlighted in a different color. The problem was already mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248872/in-vim-can-you-stop-the-color-change-of-white-space-characters-with-set-cursorl) and there does not seem to be a solution to work around the behaviour.

As a consquence I started to play with the conceal feature, which gives me mixed results. `set concealcursor=n||v||i||c` lets me control in which modes concealed characters are visible. I want to be able to see concealed characters always so I set up the following:

```
function! ConcealNonText()
    set conceallevel=1
    set concealcursor=nvic
    syntax match NonText / / conceal cchar=·
endfunction

augroup ConcealNonText
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * call ConcealNonText()
augroup END
```

As a result it highlights all spaces which are alway visible no matter which mode I'm currently in. But again there's a disturbing side effect - when I mark lines in visual mode or highlight a line with my cursorline the highlighting area gets interrupted where concealed characters are found. Just see the screenshots:

Visual mode with selected area:

[image: Vim concealed characters in visual mode]

Normal mode with cursorline:

[image: Vim concealed characters in normal mode with cursorline]

So I thought let's try `set concealcursor=ic`. This results in uninterrupted highlighted areas, but then the characters are hidden.

[image]

So is there a somewhere and somehow a solution around to the thread I mentioned in the beginning of this post or is there any way to make the cursorline and visual select areas uninterrupted when using `set concealcursor=nvic`?

Comment: A patch that implements the change has been proposed on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php): [display of listchars characters on the cursorline & visual-mode](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/oYeTcHINrrg/u4NmKV8pmGcJ)

Comment: @IngoKarkat Hm, looks promising. How are the chances we will get this into vim?

Comment: You can improve the chances by testing it and sharing your results on vim_dev. It will probably still take some time, the backlog is huge.

Comment: Is there some kind of a merge window or do the vim devs work on the backlog step by step? Just asking because I'm pretty busy at the moment.

Comment: Only Bram can incorporate patches into the mainline, and he has to work on that in his spare time. He fetches stuff from `:help todo.txt`, based on priority and his personal preferences.

Comment: This is the most annoying thing in Vim for me currently. It has been 3 years already and that proposal mentioned by @IngoKarkat never made it to a release. Not even MacVim offers a solution for this.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have 'cursorline' set. The `CursorLine` highlight group defines the highlights for the same. Either you `set nocursorline`, (which can speed line movements) or change the `CursorLine` highlight groups fg colors.

Comment: [downvote] This is entirely unhelpful. OP knows that cursorline is set, and the problem is that removing the CursorLine fg attributes does not prevent the colours from being overridden in the case of special characters.